# Inverse of $f(x)=x^3+2x+3$

Tags: calculus

I've just learned the Inverse Function Theorem which states that...

Given $f(x)$, if $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, then $g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$.

This is quite straightforward.

What is less straightforward is a homework question, in which I am to find $(f^{-1})'(a)$ of $f(x)=x^3+2x+3$ for $a=0$. I have no idea how to go about finding the inverse of this function – starting from $f(y) = x = y^3 + 2y + 3$, I end up with the entirely unusable $x-3=y(y^2 + 3)$.

Please assist.

Comment: You can use trial and error to find $f^{-1}(0)$, or if at a complete loss, dig up the rational zeros theorem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you only need to find $f'(g(0))$. And $g(0)=$? (remember that if $f(x_0)=0 \implies g(0)=x_0)$

Comment: Ah, understood. Got it, thank you!